# How do I create a canvas in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am self-taught and am trying to move away from text-based programs and into actual games and apps, but I cannot figure out/understand Microsoft's documentation to create a canvas. When I run this code all I get is the terminal. This is my code currently, copied straight from Microsoft:

```
using System
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice
{
    class Canvas
    {
        public class Canvas : System.Windows.Controls.Panel
        {
            // Create the application's main window
            mainWindow = new Window();
            mainWindow.Title = "Canvas Sample";

            // Create the Canvas
            myParentCanvas = new Canvas();
            myParentCanvas.Width = 400;
            myParentCanvas.Height = 400;

            // Define child Canvas elements
            myCanvas1 = new Canvas();
            myCanvas1.Background = Brushes.Red;
            myCanvas1.Height = 100;
            myCanvas1.Width = 100;
            Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas1, 0);
            Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas1, 0);

            myCanvas2 = new Canvas();
            myCanvas2.Background = Brushes.Green;
            myCanvas2.Height = 100;
            myCanvas2.Width = 100;
            Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas2, 100);
            Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas2, 100);

            myCanvas3 = new Canvas();
            myCanvas3.Background = Brushes.Blue;
            myCanvas3.Height = 100;
            myCanvas3.Width = 100;
            Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas3, 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(myCanvas3, 50);

            // Add child elements to the Canvas' Children collection
            myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas1);
            myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas2);
            myParentCanvas.Children.Add(myCanvas3);

            // Add the parent Canvas as the Content of the Window Object
            mainWindow.Content = myParentCanvas;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? *Also this is my first post on stack so sorry if I'm not using things correctly. Any advice on that would be helpful too.*

Comment: _When I run this code all I get is the terminal_ - You would need to create a  [WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/getting-started-with-wpf?view=vs-2019) to use this.

Comment: Also, I don't see how you **can** run this, as this code will not compile.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? (Nothing??)
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new project of correct type first. You are perhaps still creating a Console Application project. You can try WPF to create applications that have visual elements such as windows, buttons, panels, etc.

See this tutorial for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

As a side note, the code above doesn't look correct. The whole code is directly inside the class, while it should be inside a method for example.

Comment: Winforms can't run this, Canvas is a [WPF class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Delphi.Boy Thank you so much! I didn't realize that I had to use the WPF. and yes, I was creating a Console App, but I didn't realize that was what I was doing.